# Creating 3d barplots on a map

Tags: qgis, 3d-map, diagram

How it is possible to create a 3D cube with bars showing some quality, located at certain points with geographic coordinates? Is it possible to do this with some qgis plugin or, maybe, any other comparable GIS software (arcGIS or so)? The desired map would look like as follows (arbitrary picture from search results). Instead of (x-y) parameters there should be geographic coordinates, and some GIS map in the X-Y plane, and colored bars with different heights would be located sporadically (not on a grid) in a set of points, given by their coordinates.
[image: 3d barchart]

Answer (score 7):

If you have a numeric field for each point, you can use the plugin **qgis2threejs**. Here, i've taken all the towns in Iceland, and given them a random height using the expression for a field called "hite".

```
rand(0,100000)
```

you set up the plugin like this....

[image]

this creates an interactive web page you can open in a browser, you can rotate, pan and zoom.

[image]

You will probably have to change the "vertical exaggeration" setting to tweak the bar heights, if they all appear flat/too tall. You can find this setting in the "World" settings on the left.

This plugin works best if you use a projected CRS in meters (like a UTM projection). If you're using WGS84 (latitude and longitude) the elevation units are in degrees (1 degree is ~ 110000 meters) so you will need to change the values to get bars of the right length.